# ICEfaces - How can I redefine styles of components?

Tags: java, css, icefaces

is there any way to redefine styles of ICEfaces components? For example if I want to have

```
<ace:panel>
```

with blue background, blue label in

```
<ace:submenu...>
```

etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can style < ace:panel> just with style/styleClass parameter: < ace:panel style="background-color:blue">

if you want to style such elements like < ace:submenu> you should look (e.g. in firebug) which css classes are used in that component (e.g. ui-widget-header class) and override it in your css file.

Comment: Dear Cagatay, you should stop incriminating icefaces at every place in internet. I think that everybody knows now about the scandal with icefaces. I'm using icefaces since 3 years and in last time I prefer primefaces more than icefaces independent of the fork. But I think that people can use the framework what they prefer to use and there is no place in this question for such comments from you.